# How to import module into android studio by link referent?

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, module

I need to use resource from another android project (gradle) in new android phone project by using Android Studio Version 3 and Android API 23. I ready try to import by using import option in this IDE, but that module import by copy from external project. In my project has to use require share project as a framework (it is a module) that sync by SVN, so in this case I cannot update what i change into my framework. I need the solutions for using that module by just link to it without copy into project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a solution to develop and resuse your local Android library, right? So follow my steps below:

**1**- In android studio, create new android project (File > New > New Project) and save in any location your like.

**2**- Create new Module (File > New > New Module > Android Library)

Ex: **module name = MyFirstLocalLibrary, package name: com.example.local.library**

[image]

**3**- Edit **build.gradle** file which is in root of your library folder, but below the other plugins already present, add apply plugin: 'maven-publish' under **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**. This plugin will enable you to publish to a Maven repository, even local ones.

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            // Don't forget to change these
            groupId 'com.example.local.library'
            artifactId 'MyFirstLocalLibrary'
            version '1.0'

            artifact(bundleRelease)
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note: Don't forget to click on **Sync now** every time, your edited **build.gradle**

**4**- Publish module: Click on Gradle button at the top right of your android studio and you should see gradle task name **publishing**.

[image]

Then, you can see that, there are 2 tasks (**publishLibaryPublicationToMavenLocal** and **publishToMavenLocal**). Double on one of above tasks or Right click one of above tasks, then choose **run**.
And Wait to see if your build is **BUILD SUCCESSFUL**.

To Make your your library is published, your can check your .m2 repository, you should see as screenshot below:

[image]

**5**- If build is success, your library should be ready to use. Now create new android project and Update application repositories: In your main application’s project’s build.gradle, add mavenLocal().

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

**6**- Update application dependencies: open **build.gradle** (app > build.gradle) and add your local dependency:

```
dependencies {
   .....
   compile 'com.example.local.library:MyFirstLocalLibrary:1.0'
}
```

**Note: Don't forget to click on **Sync now** every time, your edited **build.gradle**

All done. Hope this was helpful :).

Comment: Thank you for give the solution, I will test this.

Comment: @BongChannarith you're welcome, I am happy to help :)

Comment: Thankful for this help. :)